# How to Replace and rejoin string (PHP)

Tags: php

A basic question... question for others but confusion for me.

What I want is suppose...

I Have 2 urls

```
1) www.something-something.com/0.0.0.0/160x160/123456789_n.jpg
2) www.I_M_Master_URL.com/something/bla-bla/(Change me)_n.jpg?lvh=1
```

I want the last number of the '`1)`'-First url that is "`12345679`" in the place of "`(Change me)`" in the '`2)`'-Second url.

So how to use str_replace in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo str_replace("(Change me)", substr($one, strrchr($one,"/"), strrchr($one,"_")), $two);
```

where `$one` is 1) and `$two` is 2) (not tested)